# Storing new data in settings

Tags: android, settings, store, android-preferences

In my application a user can save server profiles which the program will then connect to.
Since I don't know the amount of connection profiles the user will add I can't simply put it in a `SettingsActivity`.

Since I didn't want to bother with XML files again I figured I could just save SharedPreferences like this:

```
server1hostname
server1username
server1password
server2hostname
server2username
server2password
server3hostname
server3username
server3password
```

First question: Is there a better approach if I want to keep everything in the standard preferences file (contrary to creating my own file somewhere)?

Second question: I've already implemented this more or less. The strange thing is: It is working for existing settings (that were initially created via a `SettingsActivity`), but not for new entries.

Here's the source code (`Powerline` is the class name of the server profiles):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();

    // Save powerline item
    Powerline newPowerline = new Powerline();
    newPowerline.setAddress(etAddress.getText().toString());
    newPowerline.setSendPort(Integer.parseInt(etSendPort.getText().toString()));

    newPowerline.setReceivePort(Integer.parseInt(etReceivePort.getText().toString()));
    newPowerline.setUsername(etUsername.getText().toString());
    newPowerline.setPassword(etPassword.getText().toString());

    int powerlinePositionInSettings = getIntent().getIntExtra("powerlinePositionInSettings", -1);

    if (option.equals("create"))    {
        if (newPowerline.create(this, powerlinePositionInSettings))
            finish();
    } else {
        if (powerlinePositionInSettings >= 0)
            if (newPowerline.change(this, powerlinePositionInSettings))
                finish();
    }
}
```

Here is the create function of the `Powerline` class:

```
public boolean create(Context context, int powerlinePositionInSettings) {
    String positionString = String.valueOf(powerlinePositionInSettings);        
    Log.i("Powerline", "Saving new powerline to settings to position " + positionString + ".");

    try {
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit();
        prefsEditor.putString("powerline" + positionString + "Address", this.getAddress());
        prefsEditor.putString("powerline" + positionString + "SendPort", String.valueOf(this.getSendPort()));
        prefsEditor.putString("powerline" + positionString + "ReceivePort", String.valueOf(this.getReceivePort()));
        prefsEditor.putString("powerline" + positionString + "Username", this.getUsername());
        prefsEditor.putString("powerline" + positionString + "Password", getPassword());

        Log.i("Prefs", "Saving \"" + "powerline" + positionString + "Address" + "\" to be \"" + this.getAddress() + "\"");

        return prefsEditor.commit();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is the change function of the `Powerline` class:

```
public boolean change(Context context, int powerlinePositionInSettings) {
    String positionString = String.valueOf(powerlinePositionInSettings);
    Log.i("Powerline", "Saving powerline to settings to position " + positionString + ".");

    try {
        SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit();
        prefsEditor.putString("powerline" + positionString + "Address", this.getAddress());
        prefsEditor.putString("powerline" + positionString + "SendPort", String.valueOf(this.getSendPort()));
        prefsEditor.putString("powerline" + positionString + "ReceivePort", String.valueOf(this.getReceivePort()));
        prefsEditor.putString("powerline" + positionString + "Username", this.getUsername());
        prefsEditor.putString("powerline" + positionString + "Password", getPassword());

        Log.i("Prefs", "Saving \"" + "powerline" + positionString + "Address" + "\" to be \"" + this.getAddress() + "\"");

        return prefsEditor.commit();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Values stored by the change function are really saved. New values saved by the create function aren't.

Does anybody have an idea? I don't see any significant difference in the two functions.

Comment: I may be wrong, but aren't you exposing the user passwords in case the device is rooted ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. After the general storing procedure works I would add some encryption to it.

Comment: Do you have any logcat error?

Comment: At least no errors. The option variable is "create".<br>
Saving new powerline to settings to position 3.<br>
Saving "powerline3Address" to be "test"<br>
And when afterwards I'm reading the settings the new entry's not there.

Answer (score 0):

first: Don't create a file to store user data. Instead of this, create a database. So you can read,write or change the data. there is some tuts for this:
 http://thenewboston.org/list.php?cat=6 in this page you can watch tuts from #111 to #124. they will teach you.

Answer (score 0):

I will use this approach.

Usage:

// to create powerline

`new Powerline("hostname", "username", "password", 8080, 9090).create(this);`

//to update all powerlines

```
List<Powerline> powerlines = Powerline.getAll(this);
    for (Powerline p : powerlines) {
        p.hostname = p.hostname + " updated";
        p.update(this);
    }
```

PS: Tested code, modify it per your requirement:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;

public class Powerline {
private int _id;
public String hostname;
public String username;
public String password;
public int inPort;
public int outPort;

public Powerline(String hostname, String username, String password,
        int inPort, int outPort) {
    super();
    this.hostname = hostname;
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.inPort = inPort;
    this.outPort = outPort;
}

public Powerline(String powerlineString) {
    String[] vars = powerlineString.split(":");
    _id = Integer.parseInt(vars[0]);
    hostname = vars[1];
    inPort = Integer.parseInt(vars[2]);
    outPort = Integer.parseInt(vars[3]);
    password = vars[4];
    username = vars[5];
}

public void create(Context context) {
    save(context, increamentKey(context));
}

public void update(Context context) {
    save(context, _id);
}

private void save(Context context, int id) {
    SharedPreferences.Editor ed = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit();
    ed.putString("powerline:" + id, toString());
    ed.commit();
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return _id + ":" + hostname + ":" + inPort + ":" + outPort + ":"
            + password + ":" + username;
}

public static List<Powerline> getAll(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences p = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    List<Powerline> powerlines = new ArrayList<Powerline>();
    Map<String, ?> all = p.getAll();
    for (String key : all.keySet()) {
        if (key.startsWith("powerline:")) {
            powerlines.add(new Powerline(p.getString(key, null)));
        }
    }
    return powerlines;
}

private int increamentKey(Context context) {
    int key = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
            .getInt("_id", -1);
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context).edit()
            .putInt("_id", ++key).commit();
    // also assign it to current object
    _id = key;
    return key;
}
}
```

Comment: I do very much appreciate your code. But is there anything you can see in mine that appears to be wrong?

Comment: I was answering to "Is there a better approach?" part with storing one server data at one place instead of server1hostname, server1username etc. Your commit code seems to be fine. I would suggest not to call `super.onBackPressed()` in your overridden method, if you insist on calling it then move this line at the end of you `onBackPressed()` method. Also make sure that your reading code is not buggy, your commit code seems fine.

Comment: Also you can't store data with same keys. I guess you know already but just making sure. If you have stored "server3hostname" once, storing again with the same key will replace old value.

Comment: I checked my reading code by adding  the expected keys in the SettingsActivity. It was also empty there.

Anyway I now went with the database solution. It seems a bit oversized for the few data I want to store. But it's working a lot better than the settings stuff. Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I'll keep them in mind for later.
BTW: I removed super.onBackPressed().